# How do I wrangle a number of df so that they all contain identically labelled indices & columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a relative novice to pandas but use it to plot and compare trends in industrial and economic data across countries and time. The df are organised like this:

```
#create sample df

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010',
       '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'],index = ['United Arab Emirates', 'Argentina', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria',
       'Brazil', 'Canada'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010',
       '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'],index = ['Argentina', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria',
       'Brazil', 'Canada', 'Switzerland', 'Chile', 'Colombia'])         
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010',
       '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'],index = ['Argentina', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria',
       'Brazil', 'Canada'])
```

This data comes from different sources so does not always contain the same list of countries and years. In order to scatter plot them I need to wrangle the df so that they are al the same shape with identical rows & columns / lists of countries and years. I am doing this as following:

Concat the df joining on inner, creating lists of countries and years that are common to all the df:

```
#create lists of countries and years common to all df

dfList = [df1, df2, df3]

merged = pd.concat(dfList, axis = 1, join='inner')
countryList = merged.index

merged = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0, join='inner')
yearList = merged.columns
```

However I am having problems writing a function that loops through the df and removes the columns and rows (years & countries) that are not contained in yearList and countryList. The following function seems to run okay but does not change the columns / rows of the df. I'm pretty sure this is down to my misunderstanding of how variables work within loops, but haven't been able to find anything on this as it applies to complete df.

Can anyone point out why this loop isn't working or suggest a more elegant / efficient way of wrangling a group of df so that they all contain identically labelled indices & columns? Many thanks in advance.

```
#loop through all df removing all rows / cols that are not in countryList & yearList 
 
def countryyear(x):
    for x in dfList:
        x = x[x.index.isin(countryList)]
        x = x.loc[:,x.columns.isin(yearList)]
        #return x

countryyear(dfList)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your *countryyear* function your loop is working, but you have a return statement in it. When the loop reaches that return it ends the loop and outputs the first dataframe. I would iterate over dataframes outside the function, then return the clean dataframes to a list. At the moment you also aren't using the local variable x that you assign in the dataframe, you just ignore it by using x in the for loop.

```
def countryyear(df):
    df = df[fd.index.isin(countryList)]
    df = df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(yearList)]
    return df

cleanDFs = [countryyear(df) for df in dfList]
```

Comment: thank you very much for this. I like this solution. Much appreciated.

Comment: worth noting that I put the df & names for the df in a dictionary - e.g. dfDict = {'df1':df1, 'df2':df2} then wrote the clean dfs back to the dictionary -  the dfDict = dict(zip(dfDict.keys(),cleanDFs)) - makes it easier to access the dfs by name rather than position - eg. x = dfDict['df1']

Answer (score 0):

just use `loc` to find the common index and columns:

`df.loc[countryList, yearList]`

```
merged = pd.concat(dfList, axis = 1, join='inner')
countryList = merged.index

merged = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0, join='inner')
yearList = merged.columns


dfn_list = list()
for df in dfList:
    dfn = df.loc[countryList, yearList].copy()
    dfn_list.append(dfn)
```

Comment: thanks for this - clarifying I could use loc on both axes & append.